# siglas del idioma al final de la URL

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, url, laravel-6, reescritura-url

Buenas noches Actualmente tengo este sitio

https://www.wizerlink.com/

el sitio ya cuenta con la implementacion multilenguaje de laravel (app.locale, lang, ect) y funciona perfectamente

ahora bien necesito es que cuando este con el idioma ingles siempre salga las siglas 'en' al final de la url

ejemplo

http://wizerlink.com/contacto/en

https://wizerlink.com/blog/en

como se me posibilita hacerlo, la verdad no tengo un punto de partida intenter usar

algo como

```
Route::get('contacto/{lang}', function () {
return view('contacto');
```

});

la ruta del lenguaje la tengo asi

```
Route::get('lang/{lang}', 'LanguageController@swap')->name('lang.swap');
```

el controlador

```
public function swap($lang)
{
    // Almacenar el lenguaje en la session
    session()->put('locale', $lang);
    return redirect()->back();
}
```

adicionamente un middleware

```
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    /*
     * If esta a true el valor de la variable status que tenemos en locale.php
     */
    if (config('locale.status')) {
        if (session()->has('locale') &&
            in_array(session()->get('locale'), array_keys(config('locale.languages')))) {

            /*
             * Establece el locale de Laravel
             */
            app()->setLocale(session()->get('locale'));

            setlocale(LC_TIME, config('locale.languages')[session()->get('locale')][1]);

            Carbon::setLocale(config('locale.languages')[session()->get('locale')][0]);


            if (config('locale.languages')[session()->get('locale')][2]) {
                session(['lang-rtl' => true]);
            } else {
                session()->forget('lang-rtl');
            }
        }
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

y en las vistas cambio el lenguaje con

```
a href="{!! route('lang.swap', 'en') !!}">{ICONO BANDERA}</a
a href="{!! route('lang.swap', 'es') !!}">{ICONO BANDERA}</a
```

sin resultado

Saludos

Comment: Actualmente ¿cómo tienes declaradas las rutas para el tema de los lenguajes?

Comment: Actualizado amigo gracias por la ayuda

Comment: Deberías echar un vistazo a esto https://github.com/mcamara/laravel-localization#installation podría ayudarte en lo que necesitas.